# Get size parameters from xib files depending on device screen

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I've a xib file where a UIView have some constraints to the limits of the screen.

As the app is being developed to run on iPad an iPhone, how can I get the size of the UIView on runtime? I've have tried to get the size parameter of the UIView outlet, but the value returned corresponds to the value set initially in the xib file.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to get it before of after appearing the view? Views are not set on viewDidLoad

Comment: Try getting it in viewDidAppear

Comment: I've also tried to get from viewDidAppear but with same results.

Answer (score 0):

In your xib file, you should set up constraints in order to attach the UIView to the size of the controller. That way, depending on the size of the screen, it will automatically adjust to the appropriate size and you'll be able to grab the frame values from code.

[image]

Once the constraints are set up to resize according to the device screen, you can do something similar to the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    CGRect frame = self.mycustomview.frame; // replace with your IBOutlet
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting... try printing out the size of the frame in different areas and seeing when they change to fit the screen. `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. In one of those, if the constraints are set up correctly, will display the new size... if not, then maybe check that everything is connected properly and the constraints are correct?

Comment: In a fresh project it seems to work in putting the code in viewDidLayoutSubviews. So it must be something wrong in the code from the old project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the method viewDidLayoutSubviews you will find the correct size of the screen.